# Symfony Logon failing on TEST and PROD environments

Tags: symfony, security, authentication, environment

I have a symfony 5.3 installation with 2 security providers.

If I'm using the DEV environment I can login using users from both the providers, but when I change the environment to TEST or PROD I can only login using one of them.

If I add logging to my authenticator I see that I reach the function onAuthorizationSuccess with the right user on both cases, but if I'm on TEST or PROD, the page that I see is again the login page. If I switch between environments I can replicate the behaviour any time: dev ok, test and prod not passing from the login page for one of the providers. The other one ok in all the situations.

I understand that Symfony is working differently on dev than test or prod, but I'm not able to figure out what is the difference.

There are no errors on the logs and I have cache:clear a few times..

Is there any way I can debug this behaviour?

---

The behaviour changes completely if I'm on DEV or TEST/PROD environments. The test environment uses a .env.test copy of .env.dev, so it should'nt affect the result.

If I change .env to use DEV and clean cache it works: the 2 types of users can login, if I change .env to use TEST for example and clean cache again it doesn't work...

My security.yaml (relevant parts):

```
security:
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [app_user_provider, sec_user_provider]
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\WebUser
            property: login
    sec_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\Security\User
            property: login
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: lazy
            provider: chain_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\BasicAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
```

Comment: Please share more details. Did you also clear the application's cache, such that the configuration is read again?

Comment: you most likely need to delete the files in var/cache then recreate the cache. Could also be a permission file but deleting the cache then recreating the cache will most likely fix it.

Comment: I tried your suggestions with no success... it's weird that just changing from DEV to TEST or PROD blocks one type of user to login. It's verified on two different installations, so I understand it's not a local thing...

Comment: I found out the issue. 
For some reason, changing from DEV to TEST or PROD issued a security exception on the login page, redirecting (302) to the login page again?!?! After taking a deep look at the network flow I saw the 302 redirect to the same login page. Adding a 
        - { path: ^/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
at the security.yaml solved the issue.